# How do I get these costumes for my companions?

Tags: fallout-4

Hey so in a lot of videos I see the companions wearing costumes. I know for codsworth you just equip the a bowlers hat. But for the companion costumes I know cait has that n7 armour, Preston looks like woody, danse as buzz lightyear, etc. here is a link to better describe this:

How do I get these costumes for the Xbox one version?

Comment: Mods are available on the Xbox One version of the game - so that's probably how.

Answer (score 1):

You can download mods now on Xbox one for Fallout 4 (and Skyrim Remastered).

You will need a Bethesda.net account to log in first before you can download mods.

Some of the mods you are looking are probably found [here](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4?category=Clothing&number_results=120&order=desc&page=1&platform=XB1&product=fallout4&sort=popular&text=)

Here is an [Iron Man outfit](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4/mod-detail/2936969)
A [Batman Battle Armor](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4/mod-detail/2540870)
[Mass effect 3 N7 armor](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4/mod-detail/2633279)

> Always becarefull when downloading mods and combining mods. Effects
>   may be unpredictable, untested and potentially unsafe and may cause
>   your game to crash.